# NullReferenceException when getting single-property Entity from db in EntityFramework, second call works

Tags: ef-code-first, primary-key, nullreferenceexception, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code First.

I have a model like:

```
public class BlogTag
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

If I add one to the DB, things go fine. If I add relations to it, things work fine. But if I do this:

```
db.BlogTags.Find("tag")
```

on an existing tag in the DB, the first time I call it on a given DbContext it throws a NullReferenceException (rather strange). Even stranger, the second time I call it, it throws no exception and the entity loads fine. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You *must* be doing something wrong, but that something is in a part of the code that you are not showing here.

Comment: This actually appears to be related to this bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613981/ We're not ready to move to EF5 yet, but when I have downtime I'm going to migrate a copy of the project over and see if it resolves the issue.